# IRC bot for gitolite?

Tags: git, irc

Does anyone know of an IRC bot that I can hook git repositories up to, or hook directly into gitolite? Do I have to write it myself?

CIA isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If gitolite provides an rss feed, there are some rss-to-irc bots out there.